# Excel formula if a cell is equal to a specific range, copy the cell next to the matching cell

Tags: excel

Can I get an Excel formula for if a cell is equal to a cell of a specific range, copy the cell next to the matching cell, otherwise show 0.

I.e. from the screenshot in D2, check if C2 is in the range of F2:F8 and if so, show 100 (the cell next to the corresponding F2) otherwise, show 0.

[image]

Comment: I can't be certain from the way your question is worded, but I am thinking you are looking for something along the lines of `=vlookup(...`.

Comment: Wrap that vlookup in an `iferror()` to specify the 0 when there is no value found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check if the vlookup returns an error and return 0, otherwise, it will do the vlookup normally.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$F$2:$G$8,2,FALSE),0)
```

If you want to catch only `#N/A` errors (and not `#REF` errors, for example) there is another approach. Note that this requires two vlookups and therefore runs slower.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C2,$F$2:$G$8,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(C2,$F$2:$G$8,2,FALSE))
```

Comment: Can be shortened to `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$F$2:$G$8,2,FALSE),0)` Otherwise it does two vlookups and depending on the number of lookups this could slow down the calculation times

Comment: Can be shortened as Scott said, unless you're stuck in 2003 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd throw this in the mix:  `=IFERROR(INDEX($G:$G,MATCH($C2,$F:$F,0)),0)`

VLOOKUP is great for looking to the right, but if you want to look to the left then INDEX/MATCH is the way to go (although not relevant in this instance).