# Excel Formula Assistance - Conditional COPY/PAST if Criteria is true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a small question related to excel formatting and conditions.

Scenario:

I have an excel file with two excel sheets.

> ```
> > IP Address OWNER             IP Address OWNER
> > 10.0.0.1                     10.0.0.0   H2
>   10.0.0.3                     10.0.0.0   H3
>   10.0.0.2                     10.0.0.0   H4
> ```

I want a formula where if the IP address in sheet1 exist in Column 1 of sheet2 copy the owner of the row in sheet2 and paste it in the owner of the ip address matched in sheet1.

> ```
> > IP Address OWNER             IP Address OWNER
> > 10.0.0.1     H4               10.0.0.3   H2
>   10.0.0.3     H2               10.0.0.2   H3
>   10.0.0.2     H3               10.0.0.1   H4
> ```
>
> The result after the execution should look like this.

The closest thing i did was using

> IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)

To check if IP Addresses in sheet1 exist in sheet2 it returns true or false

Thank you guys

Comment: So, the [`VLOOKUP` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)?

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel formula if a cell is equal to a specific range, copy the cell next to the matching cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512892/excel-formula-if-a-cell-is-equal-to-a-specific-range-copy-the-cell-next-to-the)

Comment: Just strip out all of the `IF` and `ISERROR` code from what you already have, and check 2 columns (`Sheet2!A:B`) instead of just 1

Comment: can you write the full formula so i can try it out

Comment: Can you try to write it yourself? You've been pointed in the right direction to give you a place to start, but we're not a code writing service.

Comment: With all due respect, i have tried it my self, my request is very simple if this value exist copy the value next to it and paste it in the first one. VLOOKUP does not do that

Comment: @TheBee As I specified, just delete half your code and trim it to `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE),"IP Not Found")
```

**Sheet 1**

[image]

**Sheet 2**

[image]

Comment: Still its giving me no IP Not found on all of them

Comment: Check sheet names

Comment: Thank you man i solved it by using your formula but instead of $A i used A:A and A:B